# address.transfer(msg.value) works but address.transfer(100000) does not work

Tags: solidity

```
contract Milestone {
    address payable contractAddress = payable(msg.sender); 

        function payContractor() payable public {
             address payable recipient = 
             payable(0x0A098Eda01Ce92ff4A4CCb7A4fFFb5A43EBC70DC); 
             recipient.transfer(5000000000000);

    }
}
```

The function aboves works if i use recipient.trasnfer(msg.value) and specify the value in remix. The amount will be deducted from contractAddress and transferred to recipient.

However, the above function throws the following error when i try to specify a specific amount: The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Remix IDE, you must put the value (in your case 5000000000000) in the `msg.value` textbox and try to call your function.
This is the `msg.value` textbox and put here your value:
[image]

Comment: If i wanted to automate the transfer of ether to the recipient whenever the function is called without having to manually enter the value in remix, is it possible?

Comment: In Remix IDE you cannot send Ether value without specify it in msg.value textbox. You can test, without specific value into msg.value textbox, your smart contract: using web3js or ether.js or inject it into web3 (in testnet) and call  the function into etherscan.